# Docker Compose MariaDB ends with code 0 when using command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have a dockercompose with MariaDB+PHPMyadmin. I'm running some commands inside db service but after them it ends with code 0 while i'm expecting a mariadb server running.

I checked my docker-compose.yml without commands and it worked fine.

This is my compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    command: |
      sh -c " echo 'Starting Commands'&& apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && wget https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/sakila-db.tar.gz && tar xzf sakila-db.tar.gz &    & echo 'Extraction Finished' && mv sakila-db/sakila-schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql && mv sakila-db/sakila-data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql && echo '    Finished Commands'"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: notSecureChangeMe

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

This is the output:

```
db_1          | Starting Commands
db_1          | Get:1
db_1          | Get:2
db_1          | Get:3
db_1          | Get:BLA BLA BLA
db_1          | Unpacking wget (1.20.3-1ubuntu1) ...
db_1          | Setting up wget (1.20.3-1ubuntu1) ...
db_1          | BLA BLA BLA
db_1          | Connecting to downloads.mysql.com (downloads.mysql.com)|137.254.60.14|:443... connected.
db_1          | HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
db_1          | Length: 732133 (715K) [application/x-gzip]
db_1          | Saving to: 'sakila-db.tar.gz'
db_1          | BLA BLA BLA
db_1          | 2021-11-10 23:28:49 (1.25 MB/s) - 'sakila-db.tar.gz' saved [732133/732133]
db_1          | 
db_1          | Extraction Finished
db_1          | Finished Commands

root_db_1 exited with code 0
```

I supose thay "command" function could be overriding something but cannot find what.

Comment: Yes, the `command:` runs _instead of_ the MySQL daemon; when that command completes, the container exits.  You probably want to build a custom image and `RUN` those installation commands in its Dockerfile rather than repeating them every time you start the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the original Dockerfile for [mariadb](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/a98e19f16db72ff1f6148cd797a0cb53dacacef3/10.3/Dockerfile) you will see that they have an ENTRYPOINT and CMD which start the database.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

So try adding this to the list of command you run, like so (notice the last line in the command listing):

```
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    command: |
      sh -c "echo 'Starting Commands' && \
             apt-get update && \
             apt-get install -y wget && \
             wget https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/sakila-db.tar.gz && \
             tar xzf sakila-db.tar.gz && \
             echo 'Extraction Finished' && \
             mv sakila-db/sakila-schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql && \
             mv sakila-db/sakila-data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql && \
             echo 'Finished Commands' && \
             docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: notSecureChangeMe
```

exec'ing into the container and checking existing databases:

```
root@c875454e15cb:/# mysql -u root -pnotSecureChangeMe -e "show databases"

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             | <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
+--------------------+
```

Comment: It started but looks like the SQL file did not run.

Comment: I fixed docker-entrypoint-initdb.d whom should starts with / but i still not see SQL results. Any idea?

Comment: What sql results you do not see?

Comment: I'm placing 2 SQL files inside the init directory to initialize a new DB. it works if I place the file in a host's directory and using a volume but i want to do it directly inside the container.

Comment: i see the database being created, look, i've updated the answer with the output of the `show databases`.

Comment: With my file the db sakila was missed, but copying your one it appears.

Answer (score -1):

This is the MariaDB definition in my `docker-compose.yaml` and I don't have a problem with it.

```
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.6-focal
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <password>
      MYSQL_DATABASE: <database>
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't want to use volumes for this task

Comment: Just remove the entry for `volumes`. MariaDB will still create a volume for the database but it will be reinitialized on every restart.